# Where can I go to find one-on-one verbal Philosophical discussion?

Tags: reference-request, metaphilosophy

I don't know if **method** questions are as allowable as **content** questions, but I am seeking conversational partners to riff on and analyze ideas with as I wend through philosophical inquiries. Because I am a converser not typer at heart, I am looking for a way to find someone to have one-on-one (not group) verbal conversations (not typed) - whether by phone, skype, even face-to-face if within an hour's drive or less of Walpole NH. (Phone would be easiest.)

Is this achievable, is there any resource for finding conversational partners for philosophy? I'm guessing that the answer is no, but one has to ask.

Comment: The groups & meet-ups that work generally discuss some particular topic, & cover established philosophers, and only once a shared discussion gets going or debate if that’s the format, do people present their own ideas - with the exception of academia where people jumped through a lot of hoops to be there. Basically, if you want others to listen to you, you will need to listen to random others, and quickly wish for a way to weed out the tedious and ill informed - which you yourself may or may not be, & it won’t be for you to decide. Expect people to be read up, & to show you’ve read up

Comment: There are many sites online to find pen pals, that might be a good start.

Comment: This is absolutely a type of reference request as it asks for someone with subject-matter expertise to provide you a reference to a resource on philosophy. [MeetUp.com](https://www.meetup.com/) is the possibility mentioned below. Trying to find some people from your local community colleges or universities is another method, especially if you can get hold of a professor. As a former teacher, anyone who showed the slightest in mathematics got an earful from me.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the MeetUps website. There are philosophy groups, through perhaps not near Walpole, NH. You can start a local group and even a phone conference. I know at least one in NYC (I think called Lyceum) that was doing some Skype meetings. Another obvious approach would be to check out nearest schools and maybe hit the bulletin boards to drum up your own discussion group. You could start your own blog and chat on any number of social media sites. Sounds like it will just take some lead organizing on your part, but otherwise doable.  Personally, I don't care for phones...

Comment: This can actually work.  I started a local (Columbus OH) philosophy group on Meetup and a version of that group is still going strong over 10 years later (even without any involvement from me in more recent years).

Comment: @ChrisSunamisupportsMonica Look at you. Making a better world by bootstrapping groups of critical thinkers. Che bravo, signore!